# Как протестировать обученную нейросеть на сухом куске текста

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, тестирование, классификация-текста

У меня есть обученная нейросеть, которая обрабатывает предложения и предсказывает, является ли оно саркастичным или нет. Так выглядит моя база данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я ее обучил через RNN и fit следующим образом

```
model2.fit(sequences_matrix,Y_train, verbose = 1, batch_size=256,epochs=3,validation_split=0.1)
```

Дальше у меня есть задание, пропарсить сайт и определить, является ли статья саркастичной или нет. Но как я могу это сделать?
Статью я пропарсил, у меня есть кусок текста. Но как мне тепеь сухой кусок текста запихнуть в обученную модель? И еще, чтобы она выдавала, является ли статья саркастичной в целом или нет.

Comment: точнее, чтобы нейросеть выдавала вероятность принадлежности к классу 1 (сарказм)

Comment: `model2.predict(sequences_matrix)`, где `sequences_matrix` уже эта новая статья, подготовленная для нейросети

Comment: А каким образом вы парсили сайт?

Comment: model2.predict(sequences_matrix)  выдает массив для текста
array([[0.7472136 ],
       [0.69740653],
       [0.6614343 ],
       ...,
       [0.35714352],
       [0.40497917],
       [0.6685666 ]], dtype=float32)
что она означает? Принадлежность к классу сарказм? А если в таком случае, то как мне преобразовать этот массив на весь текст. Чтобы дать результат на статью

Comment: парсил сайт я с помощью request и BeautifulSoup
выдав тело сайла без html кода

Comment: Вопрос решил! Всем спасибо за отзывчивость!